# Why doesn't my ActionScript3 call my JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have some actionscript that plays a movie clip. When the movie clip is over I want Javascript to remove the Flash object from the page. I can't seem to get it working.

When I test the actionscript in Flash I don't get any compilation errors, and my Traces all execute when I expect. I also don't get any javascript errors thought the `RemoveFlash()` function never gets called.

Here's my ActionScript3:

```
import fl.video.*;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

MyPlayer.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completePlay);

MyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, interruptPlay);

function completePlay(e:VideoEvent):void
{
    trace("video completed");
    ExternalInterface.call("RemoveFlash");
}

function interruptPlay(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("video interrupted");
    MyPlayer.stop();
    ExternalInterface.call("RemoveFlash");
}
```

And here is my JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/swfobject2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            // Remove GreenPlayer
            function RemoveFlash()
            {
                alert("remove");
                $("#GreenPlayer").remove();
            }

            // add greenscreen swf
            var flashvars = {};
            flashvars.AllowScriptAccess="always";

                    var params = {};
            params.wmode = "transparent";
            params.AllowScriptAccess = "always";

            swfobject.embedSWF("/swf/GreenPlayer2.swf", "GreenPlayer", "200", "400", "8.0.0", '', flashvars, params);

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="GreenPlayer">asd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any Thoughts?

Comment: If you remove `$(document).ready(function(){});`, what happens?

Comment: Then the swfobject won't function correctly because it will try to write the flash object into a div that doen't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the `RemoveFlash()` function is out of the scope of the swf because you have it in an anonymous function. Try moving the `RemoveFlash()` function into the global scope (outside of `$(document).ready`) and see if it helps.

Comment: Ummm... I see. that is interesting and it brings up a slight problem. I can't define the function until after the document is done loading because I need to interact with the DOM.

Comment: Yes you can define the function before the DOM is loaded. Just don't call it until the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Your `RemoveFlash` function is local to your ready handler and flash is trying to call a global function called RemoveFlash(). Move it outside of the load handler and it'll work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RemoveFlash() {
       $("#GreenPlayer").remove();
    }      

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // add greenscreen swf
        var flashvars = {AllowScriptAccess: "always"};
        var params = {
           wmode: "transparent",
           AllowScriptAccess: "always"
        };
        swfobject.embedSWF("/swf/GreenPlayer2.swf", "GreenPlayer", "200", "400", "8.0.0", '', flashvars, params);

    });
</script>
```